# best way to post object with retrofit request

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

my request is

```
{
    "store_id": 1,
    "coupon_code":"15135",
    "payment_method":"visa",
    "address_id":0,
  "temp_address" :{
    "lat" : "45.5555555",
    "lng" : "45.5555555",
    "address_description": "test info",
    "address_title" : "test info",
    "address_type" : "test info",
    "address_name" : "test info",
  }
}
```

is send request like this

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("orders")
    fun checkOut(
        @Part("store_id") store_id: RequestBody? = null,
        @Part("coupon_code") coupon_code: RequestBody? = null,
        @Part("address_id") address_id: RequestBody? = null,
        @Part("payment_method") payment_method: RequestBody? = null,
        @Part("note") note: RequestBody? = null,
    ): Deferred<Response<DefaultResponse>>
```

how add temp_address with my request to send this data

Answer (score 1):

You can just send it all in one object!

```
@POST("orders")
suspend fun checkOut(@Body dataModel: DataModel): DefaultResponse?

    class DataModel(
        @SerializedName("store_id")
        @Expose
        var storeId: Int? = null,

        @SerializedName("coupon_code")
        @Expose
        var couponCode: String? = null,

        @SerializedName("payment_method")
        @Expose
        var paymentMethod: String? = null,

        @SerializedName("address_id")
        @Expose
        var addressId: Int? = null,

        @SerializedName("temp_address")
        @Expose
        var tempAddress: TempAddress? = null
    )

    class TempAddress(
        @SerializedName("lat")
        @Expose
        var lat: String? = null,

        @SerializedName("lng")
        @Expose
        var lng: String? = null,

        @SerializedName("address_description")
        @Expose
        var addressDescription: String? = null,

        @SerializedName("address_title")
        @Expose
        var addressTitle: String? = null,

        @SerializedName("address_type")
        @Expose
        var addressType: String? = null,

        @SerializedName("address_name")
        @Expose
        var addressName: String? = null
    )
```

Comment: have any anther way to send data RequestBody with class ?

Comment: @MahmoudElebiary I'm not sure if I understand the question. I provided the best way in the code above.